# Azure Appsetting dbuser not working

Tags: azure, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs

I am at step 6 of "Connect to a database in Azure" section

`azure site appsetting add dbuser="<database user>"`

I type in my user and it asks me for website and then slot.
I am unsure of what to put for either.

I tried this: 
http://thff.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website should be **thff** and the slot is **Production**.